# Instagram private api list reel media viewer with story archive fail response

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-story

I want to access archived stories on Instagram private api and list them.

I am using the endpoint below

`https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/archive/reel/day_shells/`

and response is

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "timestamp": 1603929700,
            "media_count": 1,
            "id": "archiveDay:18142006969109114",
            "reel_type": "archive_day_reel",
            "latest_reel_media": 1603966678
        },
    ...
    ],
    "num_results": 97,
    "more_available": false,
    "max_id": null,
    "suggested_highlights": {
        "unseen_count": 0,
        "items": []
    },
    "status": "ok"
}
```

I sent a new response to get archieved story

`https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/media/18142006969109114_1603966678/list_reel_media_viewer/`

It's response is

```json
{
    "message": "Cannot access media viewer info",
    "status": "fail"
}
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is feed/reels_media

`https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/reels_media/?user_ids=highlight:18142006969109114`

Comment: Does it support for multiple ids like: `user_ids=highlight:18142006969109114,id2,id3` ?

Comment: @Sha yes, but not using `,`, instead repeat `user_ids=`